# Can I route using href instead of component selectors in the index.HTML file in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have built an entreprise tool using ag-grid called SMCA. Now, is the time to create a home-page.
Since I am not a front-end developer, I am using a ready-made html5 template. Here's the link:

> https://bootstrapthemes.co/item/tajam-free-html5-creative-agency-portfolio-template/

This the template structure:
[image]
I have copied the assets folders in my entreprise project.
And replaced the index.html file code in my entreprise project with the code from the template( with some necessary modifications).
So now, when I run the app, I get on the browser the template page instead of my project page:
[image]
In the bottom of this page, I want the user to click on a "SMCA" to be redirected to the first tool that I have built.
[image]
I have tried with the normal method of routing. i.e: In the index.html file, I have this code:

```
<div class="single_service_content">
 <li><a routerLink="/SMCA">SMCA</a></li>
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.

In app.routing.ts:

```
  {
        path: 'SMCA',
        component: SmcaComponent
    }
```

However, SMCA in the homepage isn't even clickable.
So my questions are:
1/ What am I doing wrong exactly?
2/ Why isn't "SMCA" clickable in my homepage?
3/ Is this even the right method of integrating a homepage template into my angular project?

Comment: You have to instantiate the directive `[routerLink]` instead of just `routerLink` otherwise it's just an invalid attribute, and you can't do it from index.html since the index.html is before Angular even bootstraps, app.component.html is usually the first entry point.

Comment: is your tool within your application or is it it's own freestanding application?

Comment: @ChrisW. not true, you only need bracket binding when binding to a variable, a string literal is perfectly fine without brackets. `[routerLink]="'/link'"` is equivalent to `routerLink="/link"`

Comment: @bryan60 ya you're right, haven't had coffee yet. So second point remains that the index.html isn't registering.

Comment: did you wrote this inside the root tag or outside the root tag?

Comment: @bryan60 The tool is within my project. But I don't think it's even doable to route to a component from the index.html file. So I 'm kinda stuck

Comment: @KunvarSingh you mean the app-root tag? If so, this is outside. Is that wrong?

Comment: @AhmedGhrib, yes it is, when it is being loaded, till that angular enviroment is not ready to understand this,

Comment: @KunvarSingh should all the body of the index file be inside the app-root tag in order for routing to work?

Comment: @KunvarSingh and can you please explain "when it is being loaded, till that angular enviroment is not ready to understand this", I would like to understand how Angular works

Comment: Anything in the root tag gets removed after angular bootstrap, at least that's my experience in how we handle [pre-bootstrapping loading](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/how-to-style-angular-application-loading-with-angular-cli-like-a-boss-cdd4f5358554), I'm sticking to the first component in like generally app.component.

Comment: @ChrisW. so if I want to route to a component(my SMCA tool) from the index.html file I should write this :  <li><a routerLink="/SMCA">SMCA</a></li> . inside the root tag?

Comment: @ChrisW. and where do you think is the best place to learn about the fundamental inner workings of Angular? Because at a certain stage, it apparently becomes really important to understand not just angular but how it works

Comment: Nah, anything directly inside app-root gets replaced by whatever angular invokes to populate it. Personally I place an initial loader on the index.html with the image as base64 and the css inline to mitigate the latency of angular bootstrapping. As for learning about Angular, not to shamelessly promote someone but I'd look at Udemy and courses from Maximilian Schwarzmüller because he communicates well and is just a good dude overall.

Comment: Just to understand...are you trying to style the index.html within your angular project? Where is the `<app-root>` tag? It sounds like what you are hoping for is to build another index.html and have it link to your angular project with just a normal `href`?

Comment: @iosepa " It sounds like what you are hoping for is to build another index.html and have it link to your angular project with just a normal href?", I don't think that's possible. What I'm trying is: Integrate an html template in my project as a homepage. Something that should be easy. But, I have faced so many problems since I believe this task requires to understand how Angular works from the inside kindof.

Comment: @iosep a do you think I should write the index.html code of the template in a new component or simply copy it in the index.html of my original project?

Comment: @ChrisW.  a do you think I should write the index.html code of the template in a new component or simply copy it in the index.html of my original project?

Comment: Generally the way it's done is you treat index.html the same as any index, with your `head`, `title`, `meta`, `body` tags in there and and the app-root in the body. Then treat your app.component as the homepage more or less (assuming it's a default angular project that is) and and your app.component populates the app-root in the spot in the index.html body as it should after angular bootstraps and loads up.

Comment: Yes, if you use the index.html inside of your angular project you will be in your angular project. <app-root> is the first component. Whatever is in your app.component (that's the cli's default <app-root>) will get displayed. However, correct me if I'm wrong, if you don't include <app-root> the angular project will not be bootstrapped and routerlink will not work.